# How to make View fill remaining space

Tags: android, xml

So I have a two "sections" to my screen. I have the top section which is a ScrollView and a bottom section which is random text. The random text at the bottom will always be changing sizes, so sometimes it can take 40dp, sometimes 20dp, etc.

My question is, is there a way to make the bottom part dynamic (without loss of text) and make the top scrollview adapt to the new size and restricts its own size to "fill the remaining space" based on what portion the bottom part is using?

Like this:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the scroll view just fills the remaining space available.

I'm searching for a solution using XML only

Need HELP!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomTextView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="Test" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Or

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="Test" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Wrap both Views in a vertical `LinearLayout`;

The view which is at the top: `height = "0dp"`, `weight = 1`

And the view which is in the bottom: `height = "wrap_content"`

Comment: Thank you so much! Great explanation